# How to type into a text field in Windows Explorer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-explorer, webbot

I am trying to upload a file to a website, and when I click on the upload button (using module WebBot) it opens Windows Explorer. Am I able to output the name of the file into the File Name field? I have the full path of the file, I just need to get the actual text into the File Name box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider two approaches here:

1. Use a python library specifically for interaction with the Windows GUI. I've had good experiences with [Pywinauto](https://pywinauto.github.io/) once, seems still pretty usable at first glance. Hook this in when you expect the explorer window to open. Code may conceptually look like this - do some test run and print all available handles from the upload dialog (just guessing here as a hint, see Pywindocs):

   `app = Application().connect(title_re=".*Upload file", path=r"c:\windows\explorer.exe")`
   `dlg = app.window(title_re=".*Upload file", path=r"c:\windows\explorer.exe")`
   `app.dlg.print_control_identifiers()`
2. Check if you could simply do a POST or similar with the corresponding data. This is a very vague alternative as you do not provide information about what to upload and what the underlying backend/concept of the website is, but in the simplest case this may even be a more elegant option. A quick search brought up this short and simple example for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43942648/10192615

Comment: Sorry, very new to asking questions here. We are uploading pdf files to a customer's preferred website. I was thinking about using Pywinauto, but I couldn't remember the name of the module to save my life. What we ended up using was pynput. It allowed us to simply say: keyboard.type(filename)

Comment: For sake of completeness I updated the answer to include a SO link to an example on how to do this by POST request in python. Sounds af if this would be possible here and more simple / less overhead in this case.